# How do I pass a function as a parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

Win 7
cygwin
gcc 4.8.3  -std=gnu++11

I've researched this on stackoverflow and cplusplus and thought that I'd passed a function as a parameter correctly, even 'elegantly', but it's clear I have misunderstood something. Can anyone explain how to pass a function as an argument correctly, and why what I have won't work?

A single warning is given for the prototype and a single error for the invocation. Changing genX to genY in the comments but both genX and genY have the same warnings/errors.

```
class MyClass {
   typedef double (*func_t)(double sum);
   void driver();
   double genX(func_t fnc) { };  
   double genY(double (*funct)(double sum)) { };
   // note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 
   // '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 
   // MyClass::func_t {aka double (*)(double)}
   double myThingie(double sum) { };
};

void MyClass::driver() {
   genX(myThingie);
   genY(myThingie);
   // no matching function for call to 'MyClass::genX(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> *"Can anyone explain how to pass a function as an argument correctly, and why what I have won't work?"*

You need

```
typedef double (MyClass::*func_t)(double sum);
            // ^^^^^^^^
```

to declare function pointers for member class functions.

And get their address like

```
genX(&MyClass::myThingie);
genY(&MyClass::myThingie);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your declarations are stating that the functions expect *free* function pointers, not member function pointers. Second, you are providing function pointers to `myThingie`, which is a member function of `MyClass`, without providing an instance. Read up on C function pointer or, if you can, use [std::function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/) for a more C++'ish solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
class MyClass {
   typedef double (MyClass::*func_t)(double sum);
   void driver();
   double genX(func_t fnc) { };  
   double genY(double (MyClass::*funct)(double sum)) { };
   // note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 
   // '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 
   // MyClass::func_t {aka double (*)(double)}
   double myThingie(double sum) { };
};

void MyClass::driver() {
   genX(&MyClass::myThingie);
   genY(&MyClass::myThingie);
   // no matching function for call to 'MyClass::genX(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
}
```

Comment: It works (as you expected) but myThingie is scoped within MyClass and should be visible inside the driver. Why do I need an additional reference? And for the original typedef, since it is scoped inside MyClass shouldn't the bare function reference be sufficient, and using ::*function to scope outside the MyClass be 'more correct'? Or is this just a C++ thing?

Comment: @Arthur Schwarez The following error message of GCC explains the problem "error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&MyClass::myThingie'"

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on passing a (C-like, non-member) function pointer, use (notably for readability) a `typedef` (outside of the `class`) to declare its signature:

```
 typedef double func_sig_t(double);
```

then pass a pointer to that, e.g.

```
    double genX(func_sig_t* fnc) { };
```

However, I would use [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

```
   double genX(std::function<double(double)>);
```

it is less cheap, but you could then pass a lambda closure, e.g. call

```
   double t;
   double f = genX([=t](double x){return x+t;});
```

Or do you want to pass pointer to *member functions*? They have different syntaxes!

Comment: I think this answer does not directly address the question. The problem is that the function Op is passing as argument is an instance method and has an implicit first paramter

Answer (score 0):

`myThingie` is a member function - a pointer to it has the type `double (MyClass::*)(double)`.
A "pointer to member" is completely different from a regular pointer, and needs an instance of a suitable class that it can be dereferenced from.

You can either move `myThingie` out of the class, making it a "free" function,

```
class MyClass {
   typedef double (*func_t)(double sum);
   void driver();
   double genX(func_t fnc) { };  
   double genY(double (*funct)(double sum)) { };
};

double myThingie(double sum) { };
```

or adjust the types:

```
class MyClass {
   typedef double (MyClass::*func_t)(double sum);
   double genX(func_t fnc) { };  
   double genY(double (MyClass::*funct)(double sum)) { };
   double myThingie(double sum) { };
};

void MyClass::driver() {
   genX(&MyClass::myThingie);  // The "MyClass::" is important here, too.
   genY(&MyClass::myThingie);
}
```

In this case you need to use the "pointer-to-member" dereferencing syntax to call the function.
For instance,

```
    double genX(func_t fnc) { return (this->*fnc)(0.0) };
```